# Point inside st_dwithin with wrong results

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-joins

I want to get all points, that are in the same area. Therefore, I have the following query for my table check:

```
SELECT l.location_id, l.location 
FROM check l 
INNER JOIN check l2 ON ST_DWithin (l.location, l2.location, 500) 
                    AND l.location_id <> l2.location_id;
```

The column location is a `Geometry(Point)` data type.

The execution gives me an error and gives me more than 2 million result sets...from initial 1560 rows. The points are normally distributed through Europe and setting the threshold to 500 (m) seem to be fine. Is it may be a prolem with the data type?

Comment: I expect your points are in degrees and you've selected everything on the earth.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good bet that your SRID is 4326, and that you are testing if each geometry is within 500° Latitude and/or Longitude, which is a non-sense distance. Since everything is within 500° of each other, the expected return is 1560 * 1560 = 2433600 rows.

Try casting to a `geography` type, which uses distance units of meters (e.g., see [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) for geography inputs). Try this:

```
ST_DWithin (l.location::geography, l2.location::geography, 500)
```

It will run slower. If you want to speed it up, you can either make an GiST index on the geography cast, or convert the type to geography and make a regular GiST index there, or `use_spheroid=false` to approximate distances on a sphere rather than an ellipsoid of revolution.

Or if you don't really need exactly 500 m distance, you can approximate 500 m in degrees, which depends on your position. E.g., at 40° Latitude, 500 m is about 0.00450310° N-S and 0.00585522° E-W.

Comment: Thanks. You were absolutely right...Using Postgis, is it better to use JTS with Hibernate or postgis geo types?

Comment: @HansMüller not sure, that sounds like a different question to me.